# Scrapy : Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items

Tags: python, scrapy, response

I'm new to python and I'm trying to scrape a html with a scrapy spider but the response returns nothing. Wondering what's wrong here? Thanks for any help in advance.

The url:

https://directory.lubesngreases.com/LngMain/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/remote/api/?fn=searchcompany&name&query&STATE&brand&COUNTRY&query2&mode=advanced&filters=%7B%7D&page=1&datatype=html

My spider:

```
import scrapy
 
class lngspider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = 'scrapylng'
     user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
     start_urls = ['https://directory.lubesngreases.com/LngMain/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/remote/api?fn=searchcompany&name&query&STATE&brand&COUNTRY&query2&mode=advanced&filters=%7B%7D&page=1&datatype=html']
 
     def parse(self,response):
         for company in response.css('div.company-item row'):
             yield{
                 'name' : products.css('class.CompanyHead').get()
             }
```

Output:

```
    (workenv) C:\Users\seanl\lngscraper\lngscraper>scrapy crawl scrapylng            
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: lngscraper)
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.4.0, Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.3 3 May 2022), cryptography 37.0.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'lngscraper',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'lngscraper.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['lngscraper.spiders']}
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 5b71199b20af863b
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-05-26 21:53:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-05-26 21:53:13 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://directory.lubesngreases.com/LngMain/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/remote/api/?fn=searchcompany&name&query&STATE&brand&COUNTRY&query2&mode=advanced&filters=%7B%7D&page=1&datatype=html> from <GET https://directory.lubesngreases.com/LngMain/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/remote/api?fn=searchcompany&name&query&STATE&brand&COUNTRY&query2&mode=advanced&filters=%7B%7D&page=1&datatype=html>
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 2667801190576 on C:\Users\seanl\pythonscripts\workenv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2667801190576 acquired on C:\Users\seanl\pythonscripts\workenv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 2667801190576 on C:\Users\seanl\pythonscripts\workenv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2667801190576 released on C:\Users\seanl\pythonscripts\workenv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://directory.lubesngreases.com/LngMain/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/remote/api/?fn=searchcompany&name&query&STATE&brand&COUNTRY&query2&mode=advanced&filters=%7B%7D&page=1&datatype=html> (referer: None)
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 925,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 15651,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.974988,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 13, 53, 15, 282689),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 67300,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 13, 53, 12, 307701)}
2022-05-26 21:53:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: you should also check what HTML you get from server. Maybe it sends HTML with different CSS or it sends Captcha to check if you are human. And this may need to use `scrapy_selenium` to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to get HTML with real web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `print('url:', response.url)` in `parse()` and I see it runs this function.

First problem is that you use `CSS` in wrong way.

This `div` has two classes `company-item` and `row` and you have to use two dots (without space)

```
div.company-item.row
```

You use `div.company-item row` which means `<div class="company-item"> <row>`

---

Second problem is that you use variable `product` which doesn't exist.

It has to be `company.css()` instead of `product.css()`

---

Third problem is that it has to be `span`, not `class` in `company.css()` or you should skip `class`

```
company.css('span.CompanyHead')

company.css('.CompanyHead')
```

but this gives `HTML` and you need pseudo-selector `::text` to get only text from `HTML`

```
company.css('span.CompanyHead::text')
```

---

```
import scrapy
 
class lngspider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'scrapylng'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
    start_urls = ['https://directory.lubesngreases.com/LngMain/includes/themes/MuraBootstrap3/remote/api?fn=searchcompany&name&query&STATE&brand&COUNTRY&query2&mode=advanced&filters=%7B%7D&page=1&datatype=html']
 
    def parse(self, response):
    
        print('url:', response.url)

        # see HTML
        #print(response.body.decode())

        # save HTML in file to see it later in browser
        #with open('output.html', 'wb') as f:
        #    f.write(response.body)
            
        for company in response.css('div.company-item.row'):
            name = company.css('span.CompanyHead::text').get()
            
            print('name:', name)
            
            yield {
                'name': name,
            }
             
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},
})
c.crawl(lngspider)
c.start()
```